# Set description of an Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, wizard

I am developing an Eclipse plugin that can generate some templates for java projects.

When I call the Wizard, I can select the project wizard, but it would be great if I can display the Description of my wizard in the  "New wizard Page" when it is selected/focused....

see image for reference:

[image]

What have I tried so far:

My Wizard is a class which extends Wizard and implements INewWizard (got this auto generated from Eclipse...)

So in this class

```
class NewClassWizard extends Wizard implements INewWizard
```

I did:

- getStartingPage().setDescription("Test description"); (with no luckly results.)
- getStartingPage().setTitle("Test description");(with no luckly results.)

I tried to:
in the wizard plugin.xml by modifying and addid keys like "description" but with no effects. see plugin xml below

[image]

Does anyone of you can give me some advice with this?

Thanks

Comment: According to the doc at http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fdialogs_wizards_newWizards.htm , the `description` is a child element, not an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `<description>` child element in the `wizard` of the new wizards extension point.

This is the Ant "Java Project from Existing Ant 
 Buildfile" new project wizard with a description:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards">
  <wizard
        name="%antNewJavaProjectWizard.name"
        icon="$nl$/icons/full/obj16/new_ant_project.png"
        class="org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.datatransfer.AntNewJavaProjectWizard"
        preferredPerspectives="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective,org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaBrowsingPerspective,org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaHierarchyPerspective"
        project="true"
        category="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.java"
        finalPerspective="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective"
        id="org.eclipse.ant.ui.wizards.JavaProjectWizard">
     <description>
        %antNewJavaProjectWizard.description
     </description>
  </wizard>
</extension>
```